# my ubuntu 12.10 doesn't work and i can't install another os

Tags: 12.10, cd

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 on a low-end machine. It doesn't work properly,

After I log into the system it shows a black screen with a (movable) mouse and I've read here about a case where Ubuntu 12.10 prevented user from installing another OS from a CD, I have the same problem!

They fixed if and I am unable to do this and desperately need help!

Is there a way to force Ubuntu 12.10 to let me boot from a CD without logging In? I've configured the BIOS to boot from a CD if it can but it just goes straight to Ubuntu (I am able to acess advanced options .  the only thing i know is that the black-screen  is almost caused by the bad graphics card that's in the machine! please help

Comment: just reinstall Ubuntu and upgrade it to 12.04 or 14.04 LTS as 12.10 is dead now (not supported after 12.10) not supported means you are not able to get packages and updates for the system and use the F2 or del key to get into system boot menu and make the CD boot first prefrence

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will not prevent you from booting from CD or installing another OS.  Only your computer and its BIOS control booting.  After all, Ubuntu is not even read until the BIOS decides which disk to boot, and if it doesn't boot the Ubuntu disk, how can Ubuntu do anything?

Upgrading is another story.  If the upgrade didn't work, it can be fixed, most likely.  Have you tried pressing `ctrl+alt_F2` (or F3, F4, F5, F6, but not F7 - that's the GUI)?  If you can get a shell prompt, you can do anything, including fixing whatever is keeping the GUI from showing.

Comment: it wont show because of my bad graphics card, it warned me that the user interface might be slow but now it doesnt work at all, im in the root shell prompt, can i use it to uninstall ubuntu so i have a blank hard drive anyway? it might just be that my cd making software (infrarecorder) stopped working proply then

Comment: @user293529 might be that your cd making soft is not working properly or there might be some hardware problem

Comment: OK can i uninstall ubuntu or downgrade from the command line anyay?

Comment: Sorry guys, i'd just configured my boot options to boot from the wrong cd drive!